# Dualboot windows 8 uefi and ubuntu 13.04 64-bit

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I am trying to dualboot windows 8 and ubuntu 13.04 64-bit. Windows 8 is installed in uefi mode with secure boot disabled. To install ubuntu i followed this guide: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/12/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04-in-uefi-mode/

When ubuntu was installed the windows bootloader should have been overwritten and the system would automatically boot into ubuntu. That wan't the case for me. For me I booted into windows without being able to choose os. I followed the guide anyway and downloaded EasyBCD 2.2 and added an entry for ubuntu in the win8 bootloader. When rebootin and choosing ubuntu i get a black screeen with white text and an error message about things missing.
Any ideas?

This may have been answered but i have tried google and have not found anything that helps me. I'm new to linux/ubuntu.

Comment: With UEFI you do not need EasyBCD. Each system you install adds a folder with boot files into the efi partition and from UEFI menu should be able to boot any system. Grub will also then give you a choice. Efi folders is like having many MBR's with old BIOS based systems. You do have to choose to boot the ubuntu entry from UEFI/BIOS after install.

Comment: Ok, thats why EasyBCD didn't work then. Ubuntu is not present as an option in UEFI/BIOS boot menu. Only the harddrives and windows boot manager.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using boot-repair, which uses grub to load the uefi files.

Start Ubuntu cd as livecd and install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) onto the temporary live-system. Using apt-get.

Use boot-repair to get a runnable system with EFI-Support.

Comment: I'll try that. As I said, I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux. Care to describe what to do with a little more detail?

Comment: I installed boot repair with these instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and ran recommended repair but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Run the BootInfo report and post the link it gives to a pastebin version of the report.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5930618/  windows and Ubuntu are both installed in sdb, which is an ssd.